# ¿Cómo valido que no se repitan los registros que se ingresan?

Tags: django, djangorestframework

Este es mi modelo, serializador y servicio para guardar registros, ya logré guardar un registro el cual requiere de un `task_id` y un `auht_user_id` y si existen se guarda dicho registro, pero quiero validar que los registros no se repitan, es decir, que no haya registros con ambos datos de `task_id` y `auth_user_id`

**Model**

```py
from django.db import models
from rems.models.Effort import Effort

class Assignment(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField('id', max_length=11)
    task_id = models.IntegerField('task_id', max_length=11)
    auth_user_id = models.IntegerField('auth_user_id', max_length=11)
    hours_planned = models.IntegerField('hours_planned', max_length=11)
    hours_extra = models.IntegerField('hours_extra', max_length=11)
    hours_remaining = models.IntegerField('hours_remaining', max_length=11)
    title = models.CharField('title', max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'assignment'
        verbose_name = 'assignments'
        verbose_name_plural = 'assignments'
        ordering = ('-id',)

    def natural_key(self):
        return self.id

    @staticmethod
    def get_object(id):
        try:
            return Assignment.objects.get(id=id)
        except Assignment.DoesNotExist:
            return False

    def can_be_deleted(self):
        children_count = Effort.objects.filter(assignment_id=self.id).count()
        if children_count > 0:
            return False
        return True
```

**Serializer**

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from rems.models.Assignment import Assignment

class AssignmentSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    # attributes required
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    auth_user_id = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    task_id = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)

    # attributes optional
    hours_planned = serializers.IntegerField(required=False, default=0)
    hours_extra = serializers.IntegerField(required=False, default=0)
    hours_remaining = serializers.IntegerField(required=False, default=0)
    title = serializers.CharField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Assignment
        fields = ('id', 'task_id', 'auth_user_id', 'hours_planned', 'hours_extra', 'hours_remaining', 'title')
```

En este servicio verifico los datos necesarios para guardar un registro, el cual requiere de un `task_id` y un `auth_user_id` y verifico que existan en la base de datos

**service to save**

```py
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rems.common.helpers.ResponseHelper import ResponseHelper
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from rems.serializers.AssignmentSerializer import AssignmentSerializer
from rems.models.Assignment import Assignment
from rems.models.Task import Task
from rems.models.Auth_User import Auth_User
from rems.common.helpers.ErrorsHelper import ErrorsHelper


class AssignmentSaveService(APIView):

    def post(self, request, format=None):

        conditions = AssignmentSaveService.get_conditions(request.data)

        if not conditions['task_id_provided'] and not conditions['auth_user_id_provided']:
            return ErrorsHelper.return_missing_parameter_error('task_id or auth_user_id')

        if not conditions['task_id_provided'] and conditions['auth_user_id_provided']:
            return ErrorsHelper.return_missing_parameter_error('task_id')

        if conditions['task_id_provided'] and not conditions['auth_user_id_provided']:
            return ErrorsHelper.return_missing_parameter_error('auth_user_id')

        if conditions['task_id_provided'] and conditions['task_id_correct'] and not conditions['task_exist'] and \
                conditions['auth_user_id_provided']and conditions['auth_user_correct']and conditions['auth_user_exist']:
            return ErrorsHelper.return_not_found_error('task_id')

        if conditions['task_id_provided'] and conditions['task_id_correct'] and conditions['task_exist'] and \
                conditions['auth_user_id_provided']and conditions['auth_user_correct']and not \
                conditions['auth_user_exist']:
            return ErrorsHelper.return_not_found_error('auth_user_id')

        if conditions['task_id_provided'] and conditions['task_id_correct'] and conditions['task_exist']\
                and conditions['auth_user_id_provided'] and conditions['auth_user_correct'] \
                and conditions['auth_user_exist']:
            return AssignmentSaveService.update_or_create(request.data, conditions)
        else:
            return ErrorsHelper.return_not_found_error('task_id or auth_user_id')

    @staticmethod
    def update_or_create(data, conditions):
        if AssignmentSaveService.want_to_create(data=data):
            return AssignmentSaveService.try_to_create(data, conditions)
        return AssignmentSaveService.try_to_update(data, conditions)

    @staticmethod
    def get_conditions(data):

        # Inicializar la variable a devolver
        conditions = {
            "task_id_provided": False,
            "task_id_correct": False,
            "task_exist": False,
            "task": False,
            "auth_user_id_provided": False,
            "auth_user_correct": False,
            "auth_user_exist": False,
            "auth_user": False,
        }

        task_instance = False
        auth_user = False

        if 'task_id' in data:
            conditions['task_id_provided'] = True
            if data['task_id'] > 0:
                conditions['task_id_correct'] = True
                task_instance = Task.get_object(data['task_id'])
                if task_instance:
                    conditions['task_exist'] = True
                    conditions['task'] = task_instance

        if 'auth_user_id' in data:
            conditions['auth_user_id_provided'] = True
            if data['auth_user_id'] > 0:
                conditions['auth_user_correct'] = True
                auth_user_instance = Auth_User.get_object(data['auth_user_id'])
                if auth_user_instance:
                    conditions['auth_user_exist'] = True
                    conditions['auth_user'] = auth_user_instance
        return conditions

    @staticmethod
    def want_to_create(data):
        if "id" not in data:
            return True
        if not data['id'] > 0:
            return True
        return False

    @staticmethod
    def try_to_create(data, return_to_client=True):
        serializer = AssignmentSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            instance = serializer.save()
            if return_to_client:
                response_data = {"assignment": serializer.data}
                service_response = ResponseHelper.get_default_response(response_data)
                return Response(service_response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            response_data = {"assignment": instance}
            service_response = ResponseHelper.get_default_response(response_data)
            return service_response
        if return_to_client:
            return ErrorsHelper.return_serializer_errors(serializer.errors)
        return ErrorsHelper.get_serializer_errors_response(serializer.errors)


    @staticmethod
    def try_to_update(data, return_to_client=True):
        if "id" not in data:
            if return_to_client:
                return ErrorsHelper.return_missing_parameter_error('id')
            return ErrorsHelper.get_missing_parameter_error_response('id')

        id = data.get("id")
        if not id > 0:
            if return_to_client:
                return ErrorsHelper.return_wrong_parameter_error('id')
            return ErrorsHelper.get_wrong_parameter_error_response('id')

        assignment_object = Assignment.get_object(id)
        if not assignment_object:
            if return_to_client:
                return ErrorsHelper.return_not_found_error('assignment')
            return ErrorsHelper.get_not_found_error_response('assignment')

        serializer = AssignmentSerializer(assignment_object, data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            instance = serializer.save()
            if return_to_client:
                response_data = {"assignment": serializer.data}
                service_response = ResponseHelper.get_default_response(response_data)
                return Response(service_response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            response_data = {"assignment": instance}
            service_response = ResponseHelper.get_default_response(response_data)
            return service_response
        if return_to_client:
            return ErrorsHelper.return_serializer_errors(serializer.errors)
        return ErrorsHelper.get_serializer_errors_response(serializer.errors)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que solo pueda existir un registro para cada combinación de datos puedes definir la propiedad `unique_together` en la clase `Meta` del modelo.

Este cambio se aplicará a la base de datos, por lo que será transversal a toda tu aplicación.

Con este cambio también deberás generar una nueva migración.

#### Ejemplo

```py
from django.db import models
from rems.models.Effort import Effort

class Assignment(models.Model):
    task_id = models.IntegerField('task_id', max_length=11)
    auth_user_id = models.IntegerField('auth_user_id', max_length=11)
    # ...

class Meta:
    unique_together = [
        ['task_id', 'auth_user_id'],
    ]
    # ...
```

#### Documentación

- `unique_together`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#unique-together